# Use default image as var

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I would like to use a default image if there is no thumbnail. The image needs to be output as $image. But I can't work out how to use the image path to the default image.

```
if ($locimage) {
        $image = $locimage;
        $image = $image[0];
    } else {

        $image = "'. get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/images/images/default.png .";      
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a PHP general question about concatenating a function's returned value with a (or many) string(s).

The [get_bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) function **returns** a string instead of **echoing** it directly.

Thus you start off with:

```
// First param value: stylesheet_directory
// Using "template_url" also works unless you are using a child theme
// In that case, "template_url" will not return your child theme's directory path
$image = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
```

If you want to manually add a string to that value, you concatenate the get_bloginfo() returned value (of type string) by adding a dot (.) followed by  either single or double quotes, like the following:

```
$image = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') .'/images/images/default.png';
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does. Code only answers are discouraged as they don't teach anything.